# how to position jquery ui dialog at center of screen having mutiple iframe..?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have main page with 4 iframe inside it.

MainPage.html

```
<html>
<head>
<title>My alert</title>

<script src="jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="custom-alert.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">


</head>
<body>
  <div id="mainPage" style="text-align:center;">
  <h1>Main Page</h1>
      <input type="button" value="Trigger" onclick="$.alert('This is test msg', 'My Title');" /><br/><br/>
      <div id="page1"><iframe id="if1" src="page1.html"></iframe></div>
      <div id="page2"><iframe id="if2" src="page2.html"></iframe></div>
      <div id="page3"><iframe id="if3" src="page3.html"></iframe></div>
      <div id="page4"><iframe id="if4" src="page4.html"></iframe></div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

I want to display jquery dialog at center of screen irrespective of iframe..

custom-alert.js

```
$.extend({ 
  alert: function (message, title) {
  $("<div></div>").dialog({
    buttons: { "Ok": function () { $(this).dialog("close"); } },
    close: function (event, ui) { $(this).remove(); },
    resizable: false,
    draggable: false,
    title: title,
    modal: true
  }).text(message);

}
});
```

page1.html till page4.html as follow

```
<html>
<head>
<title>My alert</title>

<!-- Include there four files as MIME Object -->
<!-- call using $.alert("message", "title") -->

<script src="jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="custom-alert.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">


</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="Trigger" onclick="$.alert('This is test msg 1', 'My Title');" /><br/><br/>
</body>
</html>
```

How do I center dialog at center of screen not page..?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you **can't interact with the main document from an `<iframe>`** due to security policy.
It means that you can't display anything outside of your `<iframe>` by triggering an event from it.

An `<iframe>` is maybe not what you really need.

I hope this answer helps you

Comment: Ohh so what is alternative?

Comment: You will need to rethink your code. Is iframe really necessary ?

Can you use some Ajax function instead ?
You will be able to trigger any function you want anywhere you want without security restriction.

Answer (score 0):

You can call parent page function from iframe using `parent object`. In your case write below function in your **MainPage.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function showAlert(msg,title){
   $.alert(msg,title);
 }
</script>
```

And then you can call this function from page1.html, page2.html etc as below...

```
<input type="button" value="Trigger" onclick="parent.showAlert('This is test msg 1', 'My Title');" /><br/><br/>
```